# how can I get mongodb query log in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

The code is:

```php
DB::enableQueryLog();
User::find(334);        // MySql
$res = $this->subjects->simplePage()->paginate(); //Mongo
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

and the output is:

```sh
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `user` where `user`.`id` = ? and `user`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => 334
    ]
    "time" => 23.53
  ]
]
```

Is there anything wrong?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DB::getQueryLog()` will use the default connection, I think your default connection is mysql. so it print the mysql query log.

Try to use your mongodb connection, something like this:

```php
DB::connection('mongodb')->enableQueryLog();
DB::connection('mongodb')->getQueryLog();
```